# Check particular application is installed on MAC machine using install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I want to check whether particular application is installed on MAC machine using install4j. Also if application is installed on MAC machine I need path of installation directory.
Is there any API's or predefined actions available for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `com.install4j.api.ApplicationRegistry` class. In the code editor for any script property, open the code gallery and look at the examples for startup actions, there are several examples that use this class and check if an application is installed.

Comment: I tried using com.install4j.api.ApplicationRegistry class and it worked. Thanks for your reply..